# Creating a delay within a for loop in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to implement Simon game in java swing where I need to play the sequence the computer generates in the GUI. Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
for(int i : simon.getSequence()) {
    lightPanels(i);
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, e -> {
        darkenPanels(i);
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

I have four buttons each having separate colors that need to light up one after the other based on the sequence with a delay of 1 second. So say the sequence is [0,1,2]. I need the button associated with the number 0 to light up for one second and darken it. After that the button associated with 1 lights up for 1 second and so on. The result I'm getting from the code above is that all the buttons light up at the same time and darken after 1 second. I'm guessing that each timer running on its own thread is causing this problem. How do I solve something like this? I don't have much experience with Java and programming in general, so please be patient with me.

Comment: You don't show enough code here really, but near as I can tell the `for` loop can't work.  It'll block the EDT.  You need to put the whole thing in a timer.  Lighten a new panel and darken an old panel in one go.

Comment: The problem is that you are creating multiple Timers. Get rid of the for loop. The point of using a Timer is that is replaces the looping code in your application. The  Timer will generate an event every second. Each time the Timer fires you change the next button. So your Timer logic will light up one button and then increment your index. The next time the Timer fires the next button is processed based on your index value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.  I'm using a regular `Timer` because I didn't create a GUI for testing.  Lightly tested, caveat emptor.

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {       
      List<Integer> sequence = Arrays.asList( 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4 );
      TimerTask task = new SimonTimeTask( sequence );
      new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate( task, 0, 1000 );
   }
   
///////////////////

class SimonTimeTask extends TimerTask {

   private final List<Integer> seq;
   private int index = -1;
   
   public SimonTimeTask( List<Integer> sequence ) {
      seq = sequence;
   }
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
      if( index >= seq.size() ) {
         this.cancel();
         return;
      }
      if( index > 0 ) darkenPanels( seq.get( index ) );
      index++;
      if( index < seq.size() ) lightenPanels( seq.get( index ) );
   }

   private void darkenPanels( int index ) {
      System.out.println( "darken: " + index );
   }

   private void lightenPanels( int index ) {
      System.out.println( "lighten: " + index );
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Don't use the AWT Timer with a TimerTask Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Use a Swing Timer.